# How to apply Paint.NET luminosity filter programmatically?

Tags: filter, rgb, paint

I want to apply the same Luminosity filter in Paint.net

Basically, I want to calculate the luminosity component and set it to zero.
Here is what I tried so far:

- Convert RGB to XYZ to CIElab using the formulas found here : http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH
- Set luminosity (L) component to zero.
- Convert back to XYZ to RGB.

I had numerous problems using this method. Sometimes, when I convert back to RGB, some components are outside of the 0-255 range. Also, I don't get the exact Paint.net luminosity effect when I set the curve to look like a line with y = 0.

Paint.net is not open source. Could you please help me understand what it does?

Thank you.

P.S.: I program in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are simply adding/subtracting a constant from the RGB value.

```
R' = max( min(255, R+diff), 0);
G' = max( min(255, G+diff), 0);
B' = max( min(255, B+diff), 0);
```

Though, using the method you mentioned would probably produce more correct results. Getting values outside the 0-255 range is to be expected and you must deal with it. You may also want to consider gamma correction in you calculations.